# Cant reach UserControl Values inside Repeater OnItemCommand

Tags: asp.net

I use a Usercontrol in Repeater's ItemTemplate, But when i try to get it in repeater's OnItemCommand Event, UserControl's values has its default values.

```
 protected void rptNewProducts_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Basket")
        {
            ProductItem productItem = ((ProductItem)e.Item.FindControl("pItem"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that in this stage the user control was already binded to data?
It seems to me like a page life cycle issue.